error in installing 'fmt' library with vcpkg in vs code
proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/choo2/Downloads/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-dynamic -SC:/Users/choo2/Downloads/Test_Vcpkg -BC:/Users/choo2/Downloads/Test_Vcpkg/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] -- Running vcpkg install
[cmake] Fetching registry information from https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg (HEAD)...
[cmake] error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance

I have set up to use x64-mingw-dynamic, but it is still using x-64-windows.
{
    "version": 2,
    "configurePresets": [
      {
        "name": "vcpkg",
        "generator": "MinGW Makefiles",
        "binaryDir": "C:\\Users\\choo2\\Downloads\\Test_Vcpkg\\build",
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
          "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET": "x64-mingw-dynamic"
        }
      }
    ]
  }


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(TEST_VCPKG)

find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(TEST_VCPKG main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TEST_VCPKG PRIVATE fmt::fmt)


[cmake] -- Running vcpkg install Oh, do you need to set VCPKG_HOST_TRIPLET since you are using vcpkg to install packages? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration#vcpkg_host_triplet
